# Ember error while loading route

Tags: ember.js

I have a Group model that is pulling a json feed into an array and then its suppose to render it to the groups template.

My model looks like this:

```
Mdm.Group = Ember.Object.extend(); // Creating new model class

Mdm.Group.reopenClass({
  all: function() {
    return $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/1/organizations/1/groups?format=jsonp&callback=?").then(function(response) {
        var groups = [];

        response.groups.forEach( function (group) {
            groups.push(Mdm.Group.create(group));
        });
        return groups;
    });
  }
});
```

And my GroupsRoute:

```
Mdm.GroupsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Mdm.Group.all();
    }
});
```

The application is retrieving the json. The network tab in inspector loads every record perfectly, its just not spitting it back out.

In the console I get the following errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : groups:1
  Error while loading route: 
  Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
  application.js:12147
  (anonymous function) application.js:12147
  Ember.Router.reopenClass.defaultFailureHandler.setup application.js:36146
  failure application.js:35559
  (anonymous function) application.js:35621
  (anonymous function) application.js:1193
  fire application.js:1038
  self.fireWith application.js:1149
  (anonymous function) application.js:1200
  fire application.js:1038
  self.fireWith application.js:1149
  (anonymous function) application.js:1200
  fire application.js:1038
  self.fireWith application.js:1149
  done application.js:8077
  script.onload.script.onreadystatechange application.js:8330
  Uncaught #<Object> application.js:36149
  (anonymous function)
```

I know most of that is meaningless but if anyone has ever seen this before I'd appreciate any feedback.